# VNC grey screen and start on boot 12.04

Tags: boot, vnc

I have 12.04 LTS installed and I am trying to get VNC to work. I want to be able to connect to existing sessions, and have it start on boot. I followed [this](http://coddswallop.wordpress.com/2012/05/09/ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin-complete-vnc-server-setup/) guide and have left a comment to try and fix my problems but no dice. I have also tried all solutions I have found on google, including the one here, but I could not get it to work (I am missing something easy I am sure).

When I connect to the VNC session I get a grey screen with three checkboxes:

- Accept clipboard from viewers
- Send clipboard to viewers
- Send primary selection to viewers

Here is my xstartup:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
unset SESSION_MANAGER
# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
gnome-session -session=gnome-classic &

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
#x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
#x-window-manager &
```

I have also edited my to include:

```
/usr/bin/vncserver -geometry 1024x768
```

It does not start on boot, but when I run the command it starts, but I get the grey screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for solution on this [link](http://rbgeek.files.wordpress.com/2012/06/57.jpg)

Alternatively you can edit xstartup file located in your home folder by running `sudo vi .vnc/xstartup` from the terminal.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:

unset SESSION_MANAGER
#exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

gnome-session --session=gnome-classic &
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources

xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &

#x-terminal-emulator -geometry 1280x1024+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
#x-window-manager &
```

Comment: What is any difference between accepted code and code in the question?

Comment: @Dims this line has a double dash `gnome-session --session=gnome-classic &` before session

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of things which can cause the grey screen problem. Your best bet is to look at the log file in `.vnc` to see what the error is. The log file name is `hostName:display#.log`, for example, on my machine, whose name is "golden", it was `golden:1.log`.

In my case the `./vnc/xstartup` file did not have the right permissions, so `chmod +x ./vnc/xstartup` fixed the problem. I could have fiddled with the contents of `xstartup` until the cows came home and it wouldn't have helped.

Answer (score 2):

I was also looking around the net for a solution for the same problem and I found many ways people were suggesting but none seem to help me, until I found while tinkering with the `.vnc/xstartup` file by moving the `gnome-session --session=gnome-classic &` to the end of the file worked for me. Please see my working `.vnc/xstartup` file; note that I also added a second unset line due to I was getting a dbus error and I found that line while googling and at the very end there is a unity desktop session for those who prefer a default Ubuntu look. Hope it helps!

```
 #!/bin/sh

 # Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:

unset SESSION_MANAGER

unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

 # exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc


[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup

[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources

 xsetroot -solid grey

 vncconfig -iconic &

 # x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &

 # x-window-manager &

 gnome-session --session=gnome-classic &

 # gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d &
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace xstartup with the following content fixed it.
Seems the if statement is the only thing added.
I just copied this from my company working Ubuntu box. And it works immediately for me like a charm.
I have a blog post regarding VNC with vnc4server:
[how-to-setup-vnc-on-ubuntu-linux](http://www.jjpro.net/2013/10/20/how-to-setup-vnc-on-ubuntu-linux/)

```
#!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
unset SESSION_MANAGER
#exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey 
vncconfig -iconic &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
x-window-manager &

if [ -r /etc/default/locale ]; then
. /etc/default/locale
export LANG LANGUAGE
fi

vncconfig -iconic -nowin &
. /etc/X11/Xsession
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the grey screen issue.  When the event that triggered the problem occurred, I did not react proactively. But now, having fixed the problem, I know this *can* be an issue: password length.

I have run installations with passwd longer then 8.  Don't know why, but it *does* happen.  Others, not.  The system *tends* to prompt you that passwords will be truncated to 8 characters.  That is a signal.  A good behavioural rule is stick with 8 and tunnel via SSH.

The moment the passwd was changed back to 8 characters, vnc was functioning as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, all of my storage are full. Deleting files to have vacant space plus restarting the service fixed it. ( Really, I googled a lot, and then I realized, I used my VPS to download Windows 10 ISOs first from Microsoft, then SFTP-ed from there to my laptop)

Answer (score 0):

I have ubuntu 12.04 LTS and had the same problem. I don't like the Unity look and feel, so have always login using the gnome-classic. Naturally, I want my vnc to have the same gnome-classic look and feel.

I tried various solutions from other posts, but either get the grey screen or the Unity DM. Finally, I tried the answer posted by gilatpr, and that worked for me with a very minor tweak. The logs indicated --session=gnome-classic & is unknown. So I tried -session=gnome-classic &, and that did the trick. Here's my xstartup. Thanks.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
#exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey 
vncconfig -nowin &
# x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
# x-window-manager &

# . /etc/X11/Xsession
gnome-session --session=gnome-classic &
```

Answer (score 0):

Just delete `#` from `x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop` and restart. It worked for me.

Comment: You should suggest an edit on the relevant post.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `vino` instead, e.g.

```
sudo apt-get install vino
export DISPLAY=:0.0
/usr/lib/vino/vino-server &
```

If you've got the following error when connecting with VNC client:

> [No matching security types!](https://askubuntu.com/q/695611/78223)

then modify the security with `gsettings`:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false
```

For more details, see: [Getting Remote Access To Work On Ubuntu 14.04 With Vino](http://www.libregeek.org/2014/04/29/getting-remote-access-work-ubuntu-14-04-vino/).

Answer (score -1):

Is there a reason because of the security setting?

I have TightVNC on Ubuntu 14.04 and try to connect from Windows 7 from TightVNC viewer.

I have tried a lot for `xstartup` files over the internet to get the VNC working, both xwindows and gnome-desktop-fallback. But all I get is a grey blank screen.

I then tried the default ubuntu vnc server: `vino`. Very easy setup. But I cannot connect through TightVNC viewer because I get "No matching security types".

Following a post that sort of disabling the encryption of vino, I can connect from TightVNC viewer and use my Linux desktop.

See: [Getting Remote Access To Work On Ubuntu 14.04 With Vino](http://www.libregeek.org/2014/04/29/getting-remote-access-work-ubuntu-14-04-vino/).

I also tried vino through Windows Remote Desktop, grey blank desktop again.

So I am really, really confused.