# no security type suitable for rfb 3.3 supported

Tags: networking, server, remote-desktop

I'm trying to set up an RDP connection from a W10 desktop to an Ubuntu 15.10 server. The connection is made but when I'm putting in my credentials to open the desktop on my server it's turning back to the start screen of the RDP session. To resolve this I tried [the following solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/567371/connect-using-windows-rdp).

Now I get an error:

```
started connecting
connecting to 127.0.0.1:5900
tcp connected
security level is 0 (1=none, 2=standard)
error - problem connecting
```

This error occurs both on trying a local IP (within the LAN) and a WAN IP
I'm totally new to Linux so please be a bit patient with me while I'll probably miss a straightforward solution.

I've found the following error in the logfiles:

> rfbClientConnFailed("no security type suitable for rfb 3.3 supported")

Comment: i've partionaly solved it by using the command: $ gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false

Comment: now i can reach the server only when i'm logged in on the phisical server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change the /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini

i removed the conections xdrp2 -5 because these are not nessesary an i hard coded the username.

that did the trick for me

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$ vino-preferences
```

When your VNC client fails to connect with an error like “No matching security types” or “No security type suitable for RFB 3.3 supported” (or if you see a log line from vino-server like “Advertising security type 18") then type:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false
```

Then try to connect again. Otherwise, post any pertinent logs.

See: [Getting Remote Access To Work On Ubuntu 14.04 With Vino](http://www.libregeek.org/2014/04/29/getting-remote-access-work-ubuntu-14-04-vino/).

Comment: As quoted from this [article](http://tiemensfamily.com/TimOnCS/2014/04/12/vnc-vino-ubuntu-security-fix).

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04 there was no `vino-preferences` but the `gsettings...` command did the trick!  Thank you @wlraider70!