# Can't connect to Ubuntu/Lubuntu via VNC (gray screen)

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, vnc

I have Ubuntu server (18.04) and I wanted to visualize it using VNC, I managed to install `ubuntu-desktop` and `tigervncserver`, but failed to visualize. I used several ways that I got from the internet but also failed. Then I tried to install `lubuntu-desktop`, but also failed. Here is my log:

```
    user@as0018:~/.vnc$ cat /home/user/.vnc/as0018:1.log
22/06/20 10:23:32 Xvnc version TightVNC-1.3.10
22/06/20 10:23:32 Copyright (C) 2000-2009 TightVNC Group
22/06/20 10:23:32 Copyright (C) 1999 AT&T Laboratories Cambridge
22/06/20 10:23:32 All Rights Reserved.
22/06/20 10:23:32 See http://www.tightvnc.com/ for information on TightVNC
22/06/20 10:23:32 Desktop name 'X' (as0018:1)
22/06/20 10:23:32 Protocol versions supported: 3.3, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7t, 3.8t
22/06/20 10:23:32 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 5901
Error:            XKB extension not present on :1
                  Exiting
XKB extension not present on :1
Starting session: /etc/X11/Xsession
Session terminated with return code 1

22/06/20 10:23:36 Got connection from client 192.168.10.14
22/06/20 10:23:36 Using protocol version 3.8
22/06/20 10:23:44 Full-control authentication passed by 192.168.10.14
22/06/20 10:23:44 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 24
22/06/20 10:23:44 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 16
22/06/20 10:23:44 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 22
22/06/20 10:23:44 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 21
22/06/20 10:23:44 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 15
22/06/20 10:23:44 Using zlib encoding for client 192.168.10.14
22/06/20 10:23:44 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -314
22/06/20 10:23:44 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 192.168.10.14
22/06/20 10:23:44 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -223
22/06/20 10:23:44 Pixel format for client 192.168.10.14:
22/06/20 10:23:44   8 bpp, depth 6
22/06/20 10:23:44   true colour: max r 3 g 3 b 3, shift r 4 g 2 b 0
22/06/20 10:23:44 Using raw encoding for client 192.168.10.14
22/06/20 10:23:44 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 24
22/06/20 10:23:44 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 22
22/06/20 10:23:44 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 21
22/06/20 10:23:44 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 16
22/06/20 10:23:44 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 15
22/06/20 10:23:44 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -314
22/06/20 10:23:44 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 192.168.10.14
22/06/20 10:23:44 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -223
22/06/20 10:23:44 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 24
22/06/20 10:23:44 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 16
22/06/20 10:23:44 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 22
22/06/20 10:23:44 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 21
22/06/20 10:23:44 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 15
22/06/20 10:23:44 Using zlib encoding for client 192.168.10.14
22/06/20 10:23:44 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -314
22/06/20 10:23:44 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 192.168.10.14
22/06/20 10:23:44 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -223
22/06/20 10:23:44 Pixel format for client 192.168.10.14:
22/06/20 10:23:44   32 bpp, depth 24, little endian
22/06/20 10:23:44   true colour: max r 255 g 255 b 255, shift r 16 g 8 b 0
22/06/20 10:23:44   no translation needed
```

I suppose there is somethig wrong with the encoding? When I connected it via VNC Viewer, it says that the connection will not be encrypted, and after inputing password, it just turns gray screen.

Comment: Are you using VNC Viewer on a phone? VNC on Ubuntu uses encryption that those apps don't support. You have to turn encryption off in `vino`. It's been asked about a lot on the site here. https://askubuntu.com/q/695611/243321

Comment: Hi, I vnc it through windows. Btw, I don't have vino, just tigervnc, I used to install other vnc softwares such as vnc4server and vino, all failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like that there is no solutions for gnome, so I chose xfce4

```
 $ sudo apt update
    $ sudo apt install xfce4 xfce4-goodies
    $ sudo apt install tightvncserver
    $ vncserver
    $ vncserver -kill :1
    $ mv ~/.vnc/xstartup ~/.vnc/xstartup.bak
    $ nano ~/.vnc/xstartup
    (paste the follow being in the xstartup file and write out)
    
    #!/bin/bash
    xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
    startxfce4 &
    
    $ sudo chmod +x ~/.vnc/xstartup
    $ vncserver
```