# Can't get GUI when VNCing to Ubuntu

Tags: server, vnc

When I try to view a ubuntu machine via VNC, I get a grey screen with 3 checkboxes . I have tried some suggestions I read online but one doesn't help.  One still gives me the grey screen with 3 checkboxes, one gives me the grey screen without the three checkboxes, and one gives me a grid! That's following various suggestions on how to amend vnc's xstartup file.  Further elaboration below.

I have a computer with Ubuntu 18.03.3 LTS running off USB.  It gave two options, 'try ubuntu' and 'install ubuntu' I chose 'try ubuntu'.

`$lsb_release -a` shows  I am on `Ubuntu 18.04.03 LTS`

I saw [this article](https://hackernoon.com/installation-of-vnc-server-on-ubuntu-1cf035370bd3) and used these commands to install vnc server

```
$ sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop gnome-panel gnome-settings-daemon metacity nautilus gnome-terminal gnome-core

$ sudo apt-get install vnc4server
```

This shows my xstartup file

```
buntu@ubuntu:~/.vnc$ cat xstartup
#!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
# unset SESSION_MANAGER
# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
x-window-manager &

ubuntu@ubuntu:~/.vnc$
```

I think that's the default one.. I get the same error as mentioned

[VNC grey screen and start on boot 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172384/vnc-grey-screen-and-start-on-boot-12-04)

and

[vncserver grey screen ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800302/vncserver-grey-screen-ubuntu-16-04-lts)

and

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/vnc-viewer-showing-only-grey-screen-with-3-checkboxes-899386/

But the solutions there don't work for me, as i'll explain.

I get a grey screen with 3 checkboxes.

Here see I start the vnc server  (and I include some other commands I used, to list processes, as any time i'd change xstartup i'd see if the server was running, and kill it and start it again). And I checked that it is running and on what port, port 5901. And that it's not blocked by the firewall ubuntu uses by default.. ufw,  I see from `ufw status` that the ufw firewall is not enabled so no issue there. vnc server has started.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/.vnc$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 6065 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
15274 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/.vnc$ cat xstartup
#!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
# unset SESSION_MANAGER
# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
x-window-manager &



ubuntu@ubuntu:~/.vnc$ vnc4server

New 'ubuntu:1 (ubuntu)' desktop is ubuntu:1

Starting applications specified in /home/ubuntu/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/ubuntu/.vnc/ubuntu:1.log

ubuntu@ubuntu:~/.vnc$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 6065 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
15287 pts/0    00:00:00 Xvnc4
15293 pts/0    00:00:00 vncconfig
15303 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/.vnc$ lsof | grep LISTEN
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tracefs file system /sys/kernel/debug/tracing
      Output information may be incomplete.
Xvnc4     15287                 ubuntu    0u     IPv4             295628      0t0        TCP *:x11-1 (LISTEN)
Xvnc4     15287                 ubuntu    3u     IPv6             295630      0t0        TCP *:5901 (LISTEN)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/.vnc$ ufw status
ERROR: You need to be root to run this script
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/.vnc$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/.vnc$
```

I also run the `ip add` command to see my IP.

I then go to my other machine which runs windows and I enter the IP:5901 and enter the correct password and the password was accepted.

and I get this grey screen with three checkboxes  "accept clipboard from viewers", "send clipboard to viewers", "send primary selection to viewers"

[image]

I make amendments based on the first link vnc-grey-screen (172384),but get same grey screen same three checkboxes, that's with

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/.vnc$ echo https://askubuntu.com/questions/172384/vnc-grey-screen-and-start-on-boot-12-04
https://askubuntu.com/questions/172384/vnc-grey-screen-and-start-on-boot-12-04
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/.vnc$ cat xstartup
#!/bin/sh
# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:

unset SESSION_MANAGER
#exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

gnome-session --session=gnome-classic &
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources

xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &

#x-terminal-emulator -geometry 1280x1024+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
#x-window-manager &

ubuntu@ubuntu:~/.vnc$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 6065 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
15287 pts/0    00:00:00 Xvnc4
15293 pts/0    00:00:00 vncconfig
15572 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/.vnc$ killall Xvnc4
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/.vnc$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 6065 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
15575 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/.vnc$ vnc4server

New 'ubuntu:1 (ubuntu)' desktop is ubuntu:1

Starting applications specified in /home/ubuntu/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/ubuntu/.vnc/ubuntu:1.log

ubuntu@ubuntu:~/.vnc$
```

I then try an xstartup with what is in the second ubuntu link (vncserver-grey-screen - 800302)

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/.vnc$ vi xstartup
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/.vnc$ echo https://askubuntu.com/questions/800302/vncserver-grey-screen-ubuntu-16-04-lts
https://askubuntu.com/questions/800302/vncserver-grey-screen-ubuntu-16-04-lts
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/.vnc$ cat xstartup
# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
# unset SESSION_MANAGER
# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
x-window-manager &

gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus &
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/.vnc$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 6065 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
15710 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/.vnc$ vnc4server

New 'ubuntu:1 (ubuntu)' desktop is ubuntu:1

Starting applications specified in /home/ubuntu/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/ubuntu/.vnc/ubuntu:1.log

ubuntu@ubuntu:~/.vnc$
```

and i get a grey screen though this time with no checkboxes

[image]

I then attempt a third solution

If I look https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/vnc-viewer-showing-only-grey-screen-with-3-checkboxes-899386/

one suggestion says make sure the permissions of the xstartup file are 755, mine are, another says to  uncomment the following two lines:

```
unset SESSION MANAGER
exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
```

doing that (and of course killing and starting the vnc server)  `$killall Xvnc4<ENTER>` and  `$vnc4server<ENTER>`

I get this screen when trying to connect, it's like a grid

[image]

**Added**

I heard a suggestion to try looking at the log file  `/home/ubuntu/.vnc/ubuntu:1.log`

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/.vnc$ cat ubuntu:1.log

Xvnc Free Edition 4.1.1 - built Feb 25 2015 23:02:21
Copyright (C) 2002-2005 RealVNC Ltd.
See http://www.realvnc.com for information on VNC.
Underlying X server release 40300000, The XFree86 Project, Inc


Tue Feb  4 21:56:29 2020
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on port 5901
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
error opening security policy file /etc/X11/xserver/SecurityPolicy
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/Type1/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/Speedo/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/misc/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/75dpi/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/100dpi/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/, removing from list!

Tue Feb  4 21:56:39 2020
 Connections: accepted: 0.0.0.0::62323
 SConnection: Client needs protocol version 3.8
 SConnection: Client requests security type VncAuth(2)

Tue Feb  4 21:56:43 2020
 VNCSConnST:  Server default pixel format depth 16 (16bpp) little-endian rgb565
 VNCSConnST:  Client pixel format depth 6 (8bpp) rgb222

Tue Feb  4 21:56:44 2020
 VNCSConnST:  Client pixel format depth 16 (16bpp) little-endian rgb565
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/.vnc$
```

I also found this suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51415427/whats-wrong-with-my-vncserver-setting   that gives a grey screen with no checkboxes..

I heard a suggestion to try this xstartup file , in particular that the lines 14-17 might be helpful https://www.linode.com/docs/applications/remote-desktop/install-vnc-on-ubuntu-18-04/

So I used the whole xstartup file there, as i'd changed my xstartup file quite a bit.

I got a grey screen with no checkboxes, and the log says

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/.vnc$ cat ubuntu\:1.log 

Xvnc Free Edition 4.1.1 - built Feb 25 2015 23:02:21
Copyright (C) 2002-2005 RealVNC Ltd.
See http://www.realvnc.com for information on VNC.
Underlying X server release 40300000, The XFree86 Project, Inc


Tue Feb  4 23:10:06 2020
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on port 5901
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
error opening security policy file /etc/X11/xserver/SecurityPolicy
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/Type1/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/Speedo/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/misc/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/75dpi/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/100dpi/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/, removing from list!
/home/ubuntu/.vnc/xstartup: 15: /home/ubuntu/.vnc/xstartup: gnome-settings-daemon: not found

** (gnome-panel:16733): WARNING **: 23:10:09.203: Failed to request name: the name already has an owner
xkbcommon: ERROR: xkb_x11_keymap_new_from_device: illegal device ID: -1
xkbcommon: ERROR: xkb_x11_state_new_from_device: illegal device ID: -1metacity-Message: 23:10:09.279: could not find XKB extension.

(metacity:16735): metacity-WARNING **: 23:10:09.285: Failed to create MetaCompositorXRender: Missing composite extension required for compositing
# Failed to parse arguments: Unknown option --login

Tue Feb  4 23:10:17 2020
 Connections: accepted: 0.0.0.0::63052
 SConnection: Client needs protocol version 3.8
 SConnection: Client requests security type VncAuth(2)

Tue Feb  4 23:10:20 2020
 VNCSConnST:  Server default pixel format depth 16 (16bpp) little-endian rgb565
 VNCSConnST:  Client pixel format depth 6 (8bpp) rgb222
 VNCSConnST:  Client pixel format depth 16 (16bpp) little-endian rgb565

Tue Feb  4 23:10:25 2020
 Connections: closed: 0.0.0.0::63052 (Clean disconnection)
 SMsgWriter:  framebuffer updates 3
 SMsgWriter:    raw rects 1, bytes 16396
 SMsgWriter:    ZRLE rects 3, bytes 304
 SMsgWriter:    raw bytes equivalent 2375888, compression ratio 142.268743
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/.vnc$
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed instruction https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-ubuntu-18-04-vnc-grey-screen/
It has resolved my issue with vnc gray screen.

```
sudo apt install gnome-session-flashback
```

Then change the `~/.vnc/xstartup`

```
 #!/bin/sh
 autocutsel -fork
 xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
 xsetroot -solid grey
 export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
 export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP="GNOME-Flashback:Unity"
 export XDG_MENU_PREFIX="gnome-flashback-"
 unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
 gnome-session --session=gnome-flashback-metacity --disable-acceleration-check --debug &
```

Comment: Thanks.. Considering this took a year to get an answer on I have to wonder whether people  tend to use something other than VNC?!

Comment: I am normally using xrdp, its easy to use and you can connect it with the windows RDP method, it is listening on 3389, like windows RDP.
Follow this article for xrdp - https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-xrdp-on-ubuntu-18-04/